# Download a csv file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, header, fopen

[Solution found] Thank you all for your replies. I changed the button to a link and it is now working as it should.

I know this subject has been discussed over and over, I've been reading possible solutions the whole day but none solves my problem.
I need to make a script to create a csv from mysql data and download the file to the default downloads browser's folder.
As I prior said I have tried every possible solution found.
I don't have issues in getting the data and putting it in a csv. I will post a simple example from one solution I found here.

```
<?php

    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");

    function outputCSV($data) {
      $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
      foreach ($data as $row)
        fputcsv($output, $row);
      fclose($output);
    }

    outputCSV(array(
      array("name 1", "age 1", "city 1"),
      array("name 2", "age 2", "city 2"),
      array("name 3", "age 3", "city 3")
    ));

?>
```

If I put the filename in fopen, like fopen("filename.csv","w") it saves the file in the server. I need to download the file. I believe the problem is in the header. What should I do? Any help is welcomed.

I am using latest versions of xampp, php and trying it on Chrome.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I run that code, in the current version of Chrome, a CSV file is downloaded to my default downloads folder.

Comment: Thank you Quentin. After your reply I tried the php code alone and it did work. I have some other problem that won't let the download inside my web app. Maybe because I use headers prior to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to save file in server

```
fopen("filename.csv","w")
```

Then you can write code to download saved file by two ways

**First**

You can read file and pass to browser with headers

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"');
ob_clean();
readfile($filePath);
exit;
```

**Second**

You can redirect to file path like

```
header("Location: ".SITE_URL."VALID_PATH/filename.csv"); 
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, that would be an option. I just found out my mistake. I changed the button to a link and works fine.